# Translate "Need help?"

Tags: translation

I’m looking for a translation of "Need help?". I thought about "Bezonas helpon?", but I’m not sure if it can be written this way. Does the sentence need "Ĉu" or a pronoun, or is it correct this way?

Comment: Vi ja bezonas kaj la `ĉu` kaj la pronomon, do ne tro mallongigeblas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Familie mi aŭdas kaj

```
ĉu helpon?
```

kaj

```
ĉu mi helpu? / ĉu ni helpu?
```

Ekzemple kiam ni vidas ke iu havas evidentan problemon solvi taskon (nu, porti stakon da aferoj al la kuirejo, el kiu kelkaj aferoj komencas elgliti).

La unua formo `ĉu helpon?` estas mallongigo kiu eble ne taŭgas por uzo nefamilia.

La dua formo `ĉu mi helpu?` estas tuta, kaj ĝi bonas ankaŭ kiam oni volas nur proponi sin helpi. Depende de la situacio, povas esti pli facile akcepti proponitan helpon ol akcepti la bezonon esti helpata.

Comment: "Ĉu mi helpu?" is a good solution. Just four syllables and yet still a complete, grammatically correct and clear question.

Answer (score 2):

"Need help?" is a (probably ungrammatical but idiomatic) way to shorten "Do you need help?"

I'm not aware of any equally idiomatic way to shorten a corresponding question in Esperanto, so I guess the full

> Ĉu vi bezonas helpon?

would be needed.